# Spring MVC: issue between xml and annotation configurations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-annotations

I have created a simple controller

```
@GetMapping("/playerAccount")
    public Iterable<PlayerAccount> getPlayerAccounts(com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate predicate) {
        return repository.findAll(predicate);
    }
```

When I call the GET /playerAccount API, I get the exception IllegalStateException "No primary or default constructor found for interface com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate" (thrown by org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor#createAttribute).

After some (deep!) digging, I found out that if I delete the following line in my spring.xml file:

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

And if I add the following line in my Spring.java file:

```
@EnableWebMvc
```

then the problem disappears.

I really don't understand why. What could be the cause of that ? I thought that these were really equivalent (one being a xml based configuration, the other being java/annotation based).

I read [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-combining) on combining Java and Xml configuration, but I didn't see anything relevant there.

---

**edit:**

from the (few) comments/answers that I got so far, I understand that maybe using a Predicate in my API is not the best choice.

Although I would really like to understand the nature of the bug, I first want to address the initial issue I'm trying to solve:

Let's say I have a `MyEntity` entity that is composed of 10 different fields (with different names and types). I would like to search on it easily. If I create the following (empty) interface:

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<MyEntity> {
}
```

then without any other code (apart from the xml configuration  ), I am able to easily search a myEntity entity in the database.

Now I just want to expose that functionality to a Rest endpoint. And ideally, if I add a new field to my `MyEntity`, I want that API to automatically work with that new field, just like the `MyEntityRepository` does, without modifying the controller.

I thought this was the purpose of Spring Data and a good approach, but please tell me if there's a better / more common way of creating a search API to a given Entity.

Comment: Can you share the whole controller code?

Comment: The controller only contains this one method.

Comment: Did you add the spring web dependency?

Comment: I have a org.springframework:spring-web dependency in my maven pom.xml, if that's what you're asking. It works with the java annotation, without any other changes, but throws an exception with the equivalent xml configuration. No changes to pom.xml or anything else.

Comment: Depending on the Spring version there might by some sublte differences (for historic reasons). However letting people create a Predicate like that is troubel waiting to happen.

Comment: I don't understand why he used Predicate Object too that was the first time I see something like this tbh [Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum).

Comment: @M.Deinum I thought this was the correct way to go from searching on the web. Please can you point me to a documentation/tutorial that explains the current best practice to create a search API on an entity with minimal coding ?

Comment: The Predicate is a technical component. Create a form object with pre-defined fields to search on, based on that create the predicate. If you expose the plain predicate you allow query injection as you can do a lot of things with a predicate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have an example of such a query injection ? Do you also have an example / tutorial of the proper way to create a search REST API to a given entity ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see that it returned an exception, that's why I thought it was a dependency problem.
Try to make your code look like this, and it will do it.

```
@RestController
public class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    private final MyRepository repository;
    @GetMapping("/playerAccount")
    public Iterable<PlayerAccount> getPlayerAccounts() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
```

If you have a parameter in your request you add @RequestParam.
Code time (yaaaaaay) :

```
@RestController
public class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    private final MyRepository repository;
    @GetMapping("/playerAccount")
    public Iterable<PlayerAccount> getPlayerAccounts(@RequestParam(required = false) Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
    }
```

Ps: the request should keep the same variable name e.g

```
.../playerAccount?id=6
```

Comment: Well in this case the user is not able to search on the playerAccount like before. For example, http://localhost/playerAccount?name=foo

Comment: All you need to add is RequestParam annotation, I'll modify the code to make it clearer for you.

Comment: Well then how about all the other fields in the PlayerAccount ? In the end I want to be able to search on all the fields of my Object from the REST API, with minimal coding. Which is why I thought that using query dsl was convienent. But if there's another cleaner way, please point me to a tutorial that explains how to do it.

Comment: for multiple parameters **with the same name**, you can use a Map<String,String> . I don't have any links to share but I'll look for something that may help you.

Comment: Let's say I have a MyEntity entity that is composed of 10 different fields (with different names and types). I would like to search on it easily. If I create a MyEntityRepository interface that extends QuerydslPredicateExecutor (and JpaRepository), without any other code, I am able to easily search a myEntity entity in the database. Now I just want to expose that functionality to a Rest endpoint. And ideally, if I add a new field to my MyEntity, I want that API to automatically work with that new field, just like the Repository does. Using your approach, I would have to modify the controller.

Comment: I understand now the problem you are trying to solve here, and I don't have the answer to it tbh.

Comment: I added an edit to my original question that perhaps explains a bit more the main concern.

Comment: [This article](https://blog.tratif.com/2017/11/23/effective-restful-search-api-in-spring/) explains some of my concerns, though the usage of Specification still seems too complicated for me, and I thought spring data dsl query (or maybe [spring-search](https://www.sipios.com/blog-tech/how-to-generate-an-advanced-search-api-spring-boot) ?) would solve my issue. But I get this Exception and I don't understand why.